# Migration - FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I working with Code First when I run the migration I get error.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Users_dbo.Campaigns_CampaignID' on table 'Users' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Please, I need help, I don't understand why this error happens.

I saw other similar publications but I can't solve mine.

Thanks,

```
public class User  
{  
    public int ID { get; set; }  
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]  
    public string UserName { get; set; }  
    public string Password { get; set; }  
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]  

    public int CityID { get; set; }  
    public virtual City City { get; set; }  

    public int CampaignID { get; set; }  
    public virtual Campaign Campaign { get; set; }             

    public int RoomID { get; set; }  
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }  

    public bool Status { get; set; }  
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }  
    public int UserCreator { get; set; }  
}

public class City  
{  
    public int ID { get; set; }  
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]  
    public string Name { get; set; }  

    public virtual ICollection Users { get; set; }  
}

public class Campaign  
{                
    public int ID { get; set; }  
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]  
    public string Name { get; set; }  

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }  
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }  

    public virtual ICollection Users { get; set; }  
    public virtual ICollection Rooms { get; set; }  
}  

public class Company  
{  
    public int ID { get; set; }  
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3)]  
    public string Name { get; set; }  

    public virtual ICollection Campaigns { get; set; }  
}

public class Room  
{  
    public int ID { get; set; }  
    [MaxLength(200)]  
    public string RoomKey { get; set; }  
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3)]  
    public string Name { get; set; }         

    public int UserCreator { get; set; }  
    public virtual User User { get; set; }  

    public int CampaignID { get; set; }  
    public virtual Campaign Campaign { get; set; }  

    public virtual ICollection Messages { get; set; }  
}  

public class Message  
{  
       public int ID { get; set; }  
       public string Content { get; set; }          
       public string Timestamp { get; set; }  

       public int UserID { get; set; }  
       public virtual User User { get; set; }  

       public int RoomID { get; set; }  
       public virtual Room Room { get; set; }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you messed up the relationship

User -> City, Campaign, Room

Campaign -> Company

Room -> Campaign, User (Creator)

Message -> User,  Room

I guess the reason you put CampaignID and RoomID to User because you want to know who is joining what campaign and what room. But this is wrong.

What you need is a master data of users, you need only user information, no relationship with campaign or room. The relationships are considered as transaction data, which means today userA can join this room, but tomorrow userA can join another room. Through out the year, 1 user can join many rooms, many campaigns. My suggested solution will be

User -> City

RoomAttendees -> UserID, RoomID (you don't need CampaignID here because the Room already got reference to Campaign)

Campaign -> Company

Room -> Campaign, User (Creator)

Message -> User,  Room

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped me a lot. I made some changes and it worked.

Comment: Glad that it helps. Pls accept the answer if you dont mind.